# what is a good way to save an array data to mySQL in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

[image]

Its an online result marker. Once the user clicks save it gets the CA(Continious assessment) and it gets the Exam marks and the teachers remark for the particular student. I want to know how i can insert these fields into my database the right way.

```
return $request->all();
```

the above code returns the image below 
[image]

Comment: It would help if you added your table structure to this question. The answer is probably to use Eloquent. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Comment: A good way is to read the documentation of the framework you are using. Specially about Eloquents and Database. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent and https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database

Comment: im using the query builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($request->id as $id) {
    $model = new Model;
    $model->user_id = $id;
    $model->ca_mark = $request->ca_mark[$i];
    $model->exam_mark = $request->ca_mark[$i];
    $model->remarks = $request->remarks[$i];
    $model->save();
    $i++;
}
```

Query Builder

```
$i = 0;
foreach($request->id as $id) {
    DB::table('table')->insert([
        'user_id' => $id, 
        'ca_mark' => $request->ca_mark[$i],
        'exam_mark' => $request->ca_mark[$i],
        'remarks' => $request->remarks[$i]
    ]);
    $i++;
}
```

The above code has been written based on an assumption of the database table structure. In short, foreach on the ID's as this would be the student ID, and take the ca_mark, exam_mark and remark based on the key of the id.

Comment: thanks. How can i do it with the query builder tho :( @mbozwood

Comment: thank you so much! I'm at work and this was the ending part of the project. You've really helped out. I wont forget you @mbozwood :)